# Position: absolute and position: relative doesn't work

Tags: html, css

I want to announce on the top and header in the bottom but this is the output in every browser what am I doing wrong here

https://pasteboard.co/I67sPCe.png

this is my HTML code: https://hastebin.com/bocacehoka.js
this is my CSS code: https://hastebin.com/zapegulomu.css

```css
.announce {
  height: 45px;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

.header {
  position: absolute;
  height: 130px;
  background: blue;
  width: 100%;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="announce">
  <div class="header">
    <img src="img/logo.png">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Your question is unclear. what are you trying to achieve and what is failing?

Comment: attach image, what output you want?

Comment: i want announce be on top with 45 pixel height and header on bottom with 130 pixel height

Comment: Not clear enough with your explanation.  You want to achieve as per your image?

Comment: @qweqweqw, Consider my answer at the bottom, is that what you want?

Answer (score 0):

since you had `bottom:0` to `.header`, the height of it was getting increased towards the top. Hope this helps thanks

```css
.announce {
  height: 45px;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

.header {
  position: absolute;
  height: 130px;
  background: blue;
  width: 100%;
  /* bottom: 0; */
}
```

```html
<div class="announce">
  <div class="header">
    <img src="img/logo.png" alt="image">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

nested divs cannot be placed independently. Have two separate elements. consider the following.

```css
announce {
  height: 45px;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

.header {
  position: absolute;
  height: 130px;
  background: blue;
  width: 100%;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="announce">
  This is some announcement
</div>
 <div class="header">
  <img src="img/logo.png">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have added the code as per your reference image. You can adjust the `announce` and `header` height optionally.

```css
.announce {
    height: 45px;
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
}

.header {
    background: blue;
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
}

.header img {
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="announce">
    <div class="header">
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300x100">
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to give the margin to **.header img**

```css
.announce {
  position: relative;
  height: 45px;
  width: 100%;
}
.header {
  position: absolute;
  height: 130px;
  background: blue;
  width: 100%;
  bottom: 0;
}
.header img {
  margin: 82px 5px 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="announce">
<div class="header">
<img src="img/logo.png">
</div>
</div>
```